# Group tests by class & namespace in Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010, I could list my tests by full name. That way, my tests would be sorted by object, then method, then individual test case when I structured the tests as shown here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx

However, in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC Test Explorer, it lists the tests by test name (instead of "WidgetMaker.ctor.HappyPath", it just shows "HappyPath"). Is there a way to change the Test Explorer to show full names instead of the test name? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer in the end of the post :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/08/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-11-beta-unit-testing.aspx

So, wait and see/hope...

EDIT : In the mean time, you still can have a similar interface by openning the *.vsmdi file in your solution items.

Comment: In case the link ever goes down..."Not there yet, but we are working on it:
•Grouping and sorting in the Unit Test Explorer – We know that there are a lot of experience gaps in the user experience right now and this is a painful one. We are working to address this right now."